# How to make external function work with f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am trying to compile a piece of old Fortran code with `f2py` so that it can be called within Python.
However, the part with external function wouldn’t work.
Here is an MWE, first I have the `test.f`:

```
      function f(x)
      implicit double precision (a-z)

      f = x * x

      return
      end function f

      subroutine gauss(fun)
      implicit double precision (a-h, j-z)
      ! external fun

      x = 1.5
      write(*,*) fun(x)

      return
      end subroutine gauss
```

which is later compiled with `makefile`:

```
f2py -c --quiet --fcompiler=gnu95 \
        --f90flags=“-Wtabs” \
        -m test \
        test.f
```

Lastly it is called from Python:

```py
import test
f = lambda x: x
test.gauss(test.f)
```

and gives the error `TypeError: test.gauss() 1st argument (fun) can’t be converted to double`.

In a **second** attempt, I uncomment the line `external fun` in the subroutine `gauss` and get the following error message during compilation:

```bash
/tmp/tmpet9sk3e9/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/testmodule.c: In function ‘cb_fun_in_gauss__user__routines’:
/tmp/tmpet9sk3e9/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/testmodule.c:313:8: error: variable or field ‘return_value’ declared void
```

I am running out of ideas, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Uncommenting the line `external fun` and adding another line `double precision fun` worked for me, so f2py might need explicit type declaration of the function argument (though not very sure...) https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments

Answer (score 0):

I have (partly) figured it out: `f2py` needs you to explicitly specify the use of the function.
Here is how:

```
      function f(x)
      implicit double precision (a-z)

      f = x * x

      return
      end function f

      subroutine gauss(fun)
      implicit double precision (a-h, j-z)
      !! <-------- updates starts HERE
      external fun
!f2py real*8 y
!f2py y = fun(y)
      double precision fun
      !! <-------- updates ends HERE

      x = 1.5
      write(*,*) fun(x)

      return
      end subroutine gauss
```

then compile it using

```
main:
    f2py -c --quiet --fcompiler=gnu95 \
        --f90flags=“-Wtabs” \
        -m test \
        test.f
```

You can test with

```py
import test
f = lambda x: x
test.gauss(test.f)
test.gauss(f)
```

and see that the external function works for both Fortran and Python functions.

---

Two side notes:

1. Although the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/signature-file.html) says `!f2py intent(callback) fun` is necessary, I find the code can work without it.
2. You can specify multiple external functions using the same syntax, you can even use the same dummy input variable `y` for all of them (maybe not a good practice though).